# Is there a way to have a generalized github action yml file which executes based on pushes to different paths independent of each other?

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions

I have 3 different github action workflow yml files which essentially does the same thing in github action. They just differ on when to run based on which path code is being pushed on. Example:

yml1:

```
name: build docker image 1 
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "path1/**"
jobs:
  build-docker-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

yml2:

```
name: build docker image 2
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "path2/**"
jobs:
  build-docker-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Is there any way to reuse the code here and have one yml file? Note that:

1. The path is different in each case.
2. I only want a specific docker image to be built when code is pushed to that specific path.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use environment variables in docker yml files like `${PATH_TO_PUSH_TO}`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using branches for this, first I receive a variable with the name of the branch I want to execute the files/actions on, so each branch can have totally different things, it looks something like this

```
name: Workflow Dispatch
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      [webhook]

jobs:
  
  deploy-test:
    if: github.event.client_payload.branch == 'test'
    uses: {your repo}/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@test
    
  deploy-qa:
    if: github.event.client_payload.branch == 'qa'
    uses: {your repo}/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@qa
    
  deploy-main:
    if: github.event.client_payload.branch == 'main'
    uses: {your repo}/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@main
```

where the @main is the name of the branch, so you can either re use the code and just change the path or do something totally different in each branch and use the files specific for each branch.

if you decide to try this, be aware that you will need to do a checkout with

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.client_payload.branch }}
```

so that you set up the correct context and have the files specific for the branch you have selected

hope this helps